# How to show the Linux command line on 1 row?

Tags: linux, bash, putty

I discovered that on Mac the BASH command line is a bit different shown than on my Linux. I'd like to have my appearance on Linux as is on Mac.

This is as currently on my Linux:

```
namename@machine::home/username
$
```

I'd like to have it someting like this (and that kind of corresponds to the Mac appearance, at least for the 'all on 1 row'):

```
namename@machine::home/username$
```

I quess it is possible, but how do I accomplish that? Actually I'm using PuTTy 2011-07-19:r9232 b.t.w.

Comment: This isn't a programming problem, so it is off-topic for Stackoverflow. It might be suitable for Superuser, but honestly, this is a very poorly researched question. [There are no shortage of guides about how to customise a bash prompt](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=How+to+customise+bash+prompt).

Comment: If one would have known where to look for I would have found it. But that is part of the issue. Si i know now to look for customize bash prompt. Thanks for that. And I'll try to remove my question later today.

Comment: You don't need to use that specific combination of words. https://duckduckgo.com/?q=change+way+bash+looks

Comment: to all: I can't close it anymore. Admin has to do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need edit the file .bash_profile,

1. Open the terminal
2. Run the command to edit:

   nano .bash_profile
3. Insert this line:

   export PS1="[\e[0;31m]\u[\e[0;36m]@[\e[1;36m]\h[\e[1;34m]:[\e[1;33m]\w[\e[0;31m]$ [\e[0;37m]"
4. Ctrl+X to save, close and open again the temrinal
5. You will get a

   user@host:~/working/dir $

Comment: thanks. Works. Only the colouring is not to my taste. Are there and if so which parts of the line you gave concern colouring?

Comment: Grate...  this page is grate, select the colors and replace your PS1 value http://interwebninja.com/ps1-o-matic/#fce94f